# Tunning scrolling in urxvt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, scrolling, urxvt

I'm using rxvt-unicode version 9.06 at Ubuntu 9.10. I was used to aterm, where you can use SHIFT + up/down arrow to scroll the printed output with a line up or down. You can also use SHIFT + pgup/pgdown to scroll one screen up or down.

In urxvt I can use the pgup/pgdown combination as well, but can't use the up/down arrow combination. It is very useful to be able to scroll by single lines. Do you have any idea how to enable the up/down arrow scrolling?

This is my ~/.inputrc:

> set show-all-if-ambiguous on

And this is my ~/.Xdefaults:

```
URxvt*geometry:80x35
URxvt*transparent:true
URxvt*shading:40
URxvt*saveLines:12000
URxvt*foreground:White
URxvt*background:Blue
URxvt*font: -*-terminus-*-*-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
URxvt*color4:RoyalBlue
URxvt*color12:RoyalBlue
URxvt*scrollBar:true
URxvt*scrollBar_right:false
URxvt*scrollstyle:rxvt
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place the following in your `.Xresources` or `.Xdefaults`

```
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Up: command:\033]720;1\007
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Down: command:\033]721;1\007
```

See the [answer at the UNIX stackexchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44756/urxvt-scroll-just-one-line) for more information.

Comment: I am accepting this answer, as this is easier to do than to recompile from source :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had to recompile rxvt-unicode and uncomment this in `src/feature.h`:

> /* #define SCROLL_ON_SHIFT */

It was that simple.

Comment: Apparently, there is also a workaround that does not require recompiling.